# about shell_exec in php and convert it to another way

Tags: php, shell-exec

I have big problem with code in print image

I use this code to print name and image of facebook users and name color and font size

and convert name to image and print it at background with an avatar image

this is function

```
private function create_name_image ($name,$file_name,$fontsize,$fontcolor)
{
  $fontsize = $fontsize -4 ;
  shell_exec('pango-view --text "'.$name.'" --background=transparent  --foreground "#'.$fontcolor.'"  --font "'.$fontsize.'" --margin 0 -q  -o  /home/xxxx/public_html/imgnamed/'.$file_name.'.png');
}
```

Problem is with `shell_exec`, it is disabled on most shared hosts and other servers for security.

How I change this code to use another way without `shell_exec`?

Comment: Look at using PHP image creation functions eg imagestring instead of pango-view

Comment: can you explain more?

Comment: im already use image create for create name of facebook user but i want convert this function becuze shell_exec is disable for security

Comment: any help guys? :(

Comment: !! no one can covert it to php with out shell_exec??

Comment: pango-view is an external non php program you are running with the shell_exec command, there is no way to run that external program without executing it. Hence why I said do not use pango-view and just create your image in php. I've already told you the main php function you would need to look at to achieve this.

Comment: can u tell me how to make image with php? i use get from facebook name of vistor , image , color font , so it 3 image 1 background 2 facebook avatar 3 facebook name and the problem with facebook it convert it to image , so can you help me with this or i add full php file to know what need to edit? please need really help